# Convert hex to string Perl <>Cocoa

Tags: ios, cocoa, perl, hex

I need some help to transform some Perl code to a Cocoa (iOS) equivalent.

The Perl Script sends a string to a server and prints out the response. The string itself is generated from hex values. The hex values are control characters which have to be sent and are not "printable".

My question:
1) How do I convert Hex to String / String to Hex in Cocoa?

In perl I could use something like this:

```
sub sth
{   
my $sendstring = "";
my @hexvalues = @_;

foreach my $hv (@hexvalues)
{
    $string .= sprintf('%c',hex($hv));
}
return $sendstring;
}
```

Comment: Better explain what the Perl code does. Documentation for the salient parts: http://p3rl.org/sprintf http://p3rl.org/hex  The `.=` operator concatenates. Example: List `('236A', '5A', '4')` is converted to string `☺Z␄` (but the last character is really unprintable; Stack Overflow comments unfortunately do not support it).

Comment: here some more details to the script.

It takes these hex values 

    my @SENDPRE = ('63','00','01','6d','00','14','67','65','74','44','65','70','61','72','74','75','72','65','73','46','6f','72','53','74','6f','70','53','00');
 
    my \@SENDPOST = ('7A');

Then all comes together ;) with the function from comment 0

    my $content = sth(@SENDPRE) . sth(@SENDPOST);

After this the script fire up a HTTP::Request (POST) and  reads the response.


And all I want to do is this in COCOA...the Perl script works well ;)

thx